# PIC16F88 all pins High

Tags: microcontroller, led, mikroc

I have recently begun working with pic micro-controllers, and I haven't had that much trouble with the PIC16F877A series. But i found the PIC16F88 really troublesome. I don't know whether it is already a faulty IC(I just bought it), but after i wrote the following program with hopes to make an led blink, all the pins of the IC produce a high out put. I am using mikroC to write the program and pickit 3 to program the device.

```
void main() {

   ANSEL = 0;
   TRISA = 0;           

  do {
    PORTA = 0x00;     
    Delay_ms(1000);    
    PORTA = 0xFF;       
    Delay_ms(1000);    
  } while(1);          
}
```

As one can understand from the code, an LED connected to PORT A should blink and PORT B shouldn't produce and out out. Is there a particular scenario or mistake that makes all pins of a microcontroller high?

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
PORTA = 0xFF;
```

You're essentially turning on all of the pins for PortA.  A port is usually a set of 8 (or less) individual pins on the chip.  If you want to turn on just one of the pins within the port, then you need to specify which one.  There are a number of different ways to do this.  Let's say you wanted to turn on PortA pin 3.  Here are a few ways to accomplish that:

```
PORTA.B3 = 1;
PORTA = 0x4; //Hex
PORTA = 0b00000100;  //Binary
PORTA = 4; //Decimal
```

Each of the above statements will turn PortA pin 3 on and leave the rest off.  I personally prefer the `PORTA.B3` method as it allows the other pins on the port to remain unchanged.

Having said all of that, you're saying that **all** of the pins on your chip are going high when you execute `PORTA = 0xFF`?  According to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30487D.pdf), you should only see pins 17, 18, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15, and 16 turn on.  The rest should remain unchanged.  If you're seeing them all go high then I would try a different chip to ensure the first is not faulty.  I always buy these chips in bulk since they're so cheap.